# Tangent Inverse of an array

Tags: python

I want to get the tangent inverse of a set of array

```
import numpy as np
import math
```

For example (this is an array)

```
x_value=[1 2 3 4 5 6]
a= abs(x_value-125)
```

This still works fine, but when I get the tangent inverse of a:

```
b=math.atan(a)
```

I got this error: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

How should I solve this error where I can get the tangent inverse of the elements of array a?

Comment: Are you sure your example works? Firstly, it does not parse. Secondly, you can't pass list to abs (from std)

Comment: Why not use `np.arctan`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [`np.arctan`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> a = abs(a - 125)  # could use np.abs.  It does the same thing, but might be more clear that you expect to get an ndarray instance as a result.
>>> a
array([124, 123, 122, 121, 120, 119])
>>> np.arctan(a)
array([ 1.56273199,  1.56266642,  1.56259979,  1.56253205,  1.56246319,
        1.56239316])
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a list comprehension to apply the `atan` function to each element of the array:

```
a = np.abs(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6]) - 125)
b = [np.math.atan(x) for x in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
b = [math.atan(ele) for ele in a]
```